# Dynamic spinner options does not open

Tags: android, arrays, spinner, adapter

I have within a TabActivity a Spinner that will be generated dynamically. Just to test, I did so manually:

```
Spinner sp_departure = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_departure);

// This array will be generated through a database
String[] array_spinner = new String[2];
array_spinner[0] = "Departure 1";
array_spinner[1] = "Departure 2";

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp_departure.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I run the app looks ok since option selected is "Departure 1" but when I click to open the options I get some errors and the application is closed.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**- Update**

This is what was generated by LogCat: http://pastebin.com/1QPKZdKB

Comment: @dutt I updated my question with the log errors. Thanks.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues what is the status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you might have set `setContetView(R.layout.yourxml`)...,

Change it to :

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.yourxm, null);
        this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

and use

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getParent(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
```

Try, it may helps you

Comment: Hello Abhi, thanks for reply. Didn't work, I already have `setCotentView`. Layout works fine, I just can't expand the spinner. I updated my question with log errors.

Comment: in arrray adapter you have used "this", instead use getParent()

Comment: This is all I have in `onCreate`, still doesn't work, same error. http://pastebin.com/wNt5uEpM

Comment: oops, sorry. is now working with these two changes. thank you!